# Erro ao alterar label - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, label, fxml

Estou tentando alterar uma label `lbl1` pelo método construtor do controller do FXML.

```
public class TestController extends Application {

@FXML
private Label lbl1;

public TestController()

{

lbl1.setText("Teste");

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) 

{                       
}

public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Ao tentar alterar o texto da label, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
>   /D:/Users/Gabriel%20Augusto/eclipse-workspace/Dialog/bin/FXML/Test.fxml:10
>
> at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)     at
>   application.Test.start(Login.java:47)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
>   Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   application.TestController.(TestController.java:198)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)  at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)    ... 12 more

O controller está devidamente configurado ao FXML. O erro ocorre ao tentar fazer a alteração do texto da label, contida no FXML.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar o padrão MVC, onde você separa sua view da controller.

Pelo que vi você está usando uma controller para iniciar a aplicação, o que não se faz. você deve usar uma Main (extends Application) apenas para iniciar sua tela principal.

E por sua vez essa tela principal (view(FXML)) tem que ter uma controller essa sim vai controlar tudo da sua tela.

ficando assim:

**Main**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    carregar sua FXML principal...
}
```

no FXML da view principal você seta o fx:controller="..."

Essa controller é que terá a referencia se sua Label:

```
@FXML
private Label lbl1;
```

assim você poderá setar o texto que quiser e seguindo os padrões...

Ah, e implemente o Initializable na sua classe controle para puder alterar o Label:

```
public class SUA_CONTROLLER implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private Label lbl1;;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        lbl1.setText(....);
    }
}
```